# Is it better to use JsonField or multiple model fields for a Django Model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, django-models

For example,

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    descriptions = models.JsonField()
```

Or

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    description_1 = models.TextField()
    description_2 = models.TextField()
    description_3 = models.TextField()
    description_4 = models.TextField()
    description_5 = models.TextField()
```

Assume that I have a limited (max 5) number of descriptions.
Which approach is better and would be considered as good practice?

Comment: i prefer using several fields instead of a JSON Field - JSON Fields have a small use case - if you get data and it varies in structure, content and size

Comment: in your case, it is better to make new model for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am generally in favour of multiple models rather than using JSON, though there is still a time and a place for the JSON field. You have a number of description fields, you can do something like this:

```py
class TestModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class TestModelDescription(models.Model):
    test_model = models.ForeignKey(TestModel, ...
    description = models.CharField(...
```

You can then have any number of descriptions and access them like this:

```
test_model.testmodeldescription_set.all()
```